# Постоянное хранение массива объектов в приложении на разных языках перевода

Tags: java, android, массивы

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - есть база заданий, в одном задании  несколько свойств (Название, номер, сложность, описание, картинка). Как все это сохранить в базе приложения при этом иметь поддержку нескольких языков? Не могу прикинуть универсальную реализацию, буду рад за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем представленна база? Как она попадает к пользователю. Предположу что SQLite, и база зашита в apk, исходя из описания. В прочем, почти в любом случае ответ - не средствами андроида. Придется создавать под каждый язык свою базу. Можно, конечно, все локали уместить в одну базу, просто использую префиксы таблиц или заморочившись с многоуровневой базой, но это куча головной боли, горы кода и минимум толку. Лучшее что можно сделать - базы для всех языков разместить на сервере и скачивать исходя из предпочтений пользователя и\или локали на устройстве.

Если хотите именно "вшить" базу в приложение, то учитывайте, что SQLite база, расположенная в asset'ах или raw, не может быть открыта. Ее придется скопировать во внешнее/внутреннее хранилище и открыть оттуда. А еще размер apk для загрузки в маркет должен иметь размер менее 100мб, и если база большая, да еще с картинками, держать кучу языков на в apk не просто бессмысленно, но проблемно. Но если все это не останавливает, то вот еще два варианта:

Если вы хотите, чтобы именно средства локализации андроида сделали часть работы за вас, то создаем в ресурсах raw с параметрами по локали, как мипмапы для разных плотностей экранов. Например для русского языка это raw-ru-rRU. Незабываем про папку с языком по умолчанию. Тогда в коде вы работает с базой как будто она одна, копируете ее на диск и андроид сам выберет нужную. Подход плохой, т.к. желаемый пользователем язык может не совпасть с локалью, или вы не указали его локаль и открывается база с языком по умолчанию... В общем, много проблем

Потому третий вариант. Кладем все базы в одну папку, raw или assets, при загрузке спрашиваем у юзера какой язык ему подавать, выдав первым в списке тот, что соответствует локали, и работать с ним.